# Setting CurrentCulture from DropnDown in MasterPage

Tags: asp.net

What is the best practice to set the `CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` from a DrownDownList in a MasterPage?

I don't want to override `InitializeCulture()` in every page.
Could it be stored in a Session variable and set in a HttpModule or HttpHandler?

An additional problem i ran into is that if there are databound language-dependant controls on the page they will need to be databound after the language has changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have most often chosen to create a pase page class and override InitializeCulture() there. All pages inherit from the base page so all logic is encapsulated in the base page. This works for me because I use the querystring to pass language preference changes.

InitializeCulture() has logic to check for querystring argument, existing session value, cookie preference, defaulting to the browser's current culture.

I suppose you could do a redirect in the masterpage dropdown change event.

Comment: What do you do when the user changes language on a page and due to the language change you need to databind again? Somehow you want to know if you need to databind, or not.

Comment: Persist the language and redirect to yourself.

Comment: As Dirk said, I persist the language in session and cookie. Redirecting will reload the page possibly losing state. You must balance the trade of between the usefulness of instant language switching with the difficulty of maintaining current state (or value of maintaining state).
Unless your app has a special language related purpose, a user would likely switch language before interacting with app and only do so once, so the value of instant switching is limited. I have often made the feature available anyway, accepting the low risk that a user might lose state in some unusual circumstance.

Comment: When the user selects a different language i handle it (the dropdown is know and the value gotten from the context.Request) in my HttpHandler, storing the language in session and setting the thread's culturecode accoordingly. (In this specific app i have most of the time the user's preferred language will be his browser language, which will be set by default by my app). Is there anything wrong with doing it like this?

Answer (score 1):

I store the culture in a cookie and then set it in the Application_BeginRequest of the global.asax.  When you first set it though you have to Server.Transfer(Request.Url.LocalPath) because the selectedindex changed event fires too late in the lifecycle to take affect.  Not sure if its the best but it works for me.